# Is there a way to look through wall paintings for pencil writings?

Tags: paint, repainting

I had pencil writings on the wall from my childhood and this year I came back home and I found that my parents had the wall repainted with white paint. I should've taken a picture of these writings as they are part of my childhood memories. Is there still a way to look through the white paint for my pencil writings?

Comment: Don’t they x-ray paintings?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, but they have easy access to both sides.

Comment: @DoxyLover can get access to both sides of many walls ...

Comment: Thanks for you guys help! @SolarMikeMay I ask what's X-ray paintings? Googled it didn't really understand... and what does "get access to both sides" mean? Thanks

Comment: it depends on the paint, but probably not.

Comment: If you wait a bit it may show its self. My son drew on a wall I had primered  with a carpenters pencil with a nice wide point. Several months later the paint bubbled and peeled, but only along the pencil marks. It seems that the graphite kept the paint from adhering. I had to sand, reprime and repaint.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis and @mikes! Let me wait for a few months and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not necessarily easy to do without specialist equipment. It's done by forensic document examiners and art historians.

> we can retrieve under-drawings below paintings by looking at them in
>   infrared light. This is because the carbon used by artists to make
>   their under-drawing absorbs light at that range of the spectrum ...
>   Ultraviolet light has often been used to look at faint text in medieval manuscripts,

http://archimedespalimpsest.org/about/imaging/processing.php

> Spectral imaging recovers faded or erased text by capturing details
>   about the ink and the parchment at different wavelengths. And because
>   different wavelengths of light convey information unique to that
>   spectrum, traces of iron ink, for instance, appear one way in infrared
>   light, another way in ultraviolet, and, perhaps, not at all in visible
>   light. Multispectral imaging collects the different information and
>   recombines them into composite spectral signatures.

https://www.rit.edu/showcase/index.php?id=325

> Infrared imaging has been used to analyze old documents and works of
>   art since the 1960s. But the equipment typically used by conservators
>   for this kind of analysis is bulky and pricey; the systems can run
>   more than $100,000. **Falco has developed a hacked hand-held version**
>   —not as precise in resolution, but cheaper and more portable, making
>   it possible to image paintings right on the walls they adorn. ...
>   Falco can also jigger his camera to photograph ultraviolet light,
>   which can reveal otherwise hidden details, most notably fluorescence.

http://nautil.us/blog/looking-through-paintings-to-see-whats-hidden

If it's a couple of coats of emulsion paint, and stain blocker wasn't used, you could try with a close-up infrared and ultraviolet light sources (infrared LEDs are cheap and used for CCTV, ultraviolet is used for disco lights and insect killers) and see if you can detect anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed resources! I will look into them.